# PC resets, could it be my PSU?

Tags: power-supply, shutdown, reboot

I just bought a Geforce 2080TI Matrix.

When i play games it works fine for a hour or 2.  Then my PC just dose a fast reset, powers everything down and starts up again.

So i was wondring, could it be my "older" PSU causing this problem?

My specs are:
I7-8700K
32GB ram
3x SSD 
1 net card
4-5 Fans
Corsair H100i
XFX ProSeries XXX Edition 850W PSU

Even though my PSU got alot of power, could it be too old? OR could it be another problem?

Comment: It definitely could be the power supply. Do you have another one you can swap it out with for testing purposes?

Comment: sadly no, would have done it, if i had. 

but would a new PSU on the same W as my old one be the same or dose new PSUs have new standards?

Comment: A new PSU can replace an older one as long as it has sufficient power. I would also check the CPU temps when under load, with CoreTemp. There are a lot of possibilities right now. Also look in Event Viewer and see if it could be a software-related issue.

Comment: I have looked at the event log, did not give me much infomation. I get a Critical Event ID 31 and som warning event id 10016, thats it.

Comment: Do you have a spare hard drive? You could put a clean install of Windows on a spare drive and try playing your game on it for a while. That will tell you if it's the hardware (if the problem persists) or a software issue (if a clean install solves it).

Comment: Have tried clean install. Did not work.

But i also get this error: The local adapter does not support an important Low Energy controller state to support peripheral mode. The minimum required supported state mask is 0x2491f7fffff; got 0xffffffff. Low Energy peripheral role functionality will not be available.